# How to get String[] from ArrayList<String[]>, I want to actually get String at index 0 from ArrayList<String[]>?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I have a Class

```
public class DataRatesString {

private String[] ab1 = {"Auto moto sdhv davjdn adadk", "Rs. 355"} ;
    private String[] ab2 = {"sjg atoiu ", "Rs. 200"} ;
    private String[] ab3 = {"go to UTOP atup auto", "Rs. 3279"} ;
    private String[] ab4 = {"Hid to putho", "Rs. 2424"} ;
    private String[] abo5 = {"pithoo to bittu", "Rs. 8457"} ;

private ArrayList<String[]> abCollection = new ArrayList<>();

 public void setAbCollection() {
        abCollection.add(ab1);
        abCollection.add(ab2);
        abCollection.add(ab3);
        abCollection.add(ab4);
        abCollection.add(ab5);
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getAbCollection(){
        return abCollection;
    }

}
```

I have another class from which I am calling the list

```
DataRatesString dataRatesString = new DataRatesString();
dataRatesString.setAbCollection();

        ArrayList<String[]> ratesarray = dataRatesString.getAbCollection();
```

Now I want to get all the strings at position 0 of the Arraylist String[]

I have created a method in the same class but since I am new to java I am unable to figure out exactly how to do it.

This is the method that I tried to make

```
private List<String> getRatesItemNamelist(){
String[] arraylist;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        arraylist = new String[ratesarray.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < ratesarray.size(); i++) {
        arraylist = ratesarray.get(i);

        }

            list.add(0, arraylist[arraylist.length]);

        return list;
    }
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private List<String> getRatesItemNamelist(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] rates : ratesarray) {
        list.add(rates[0]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here in the for loop, rates[0] will get the first `String` from the `String[]` array for each element in ratesarray `ArrayList`.

So the `getRatesItemNamelist()` function will return a list of String at index 0 from ArrayList ratesarray.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood properly, you want all arraylist data at position 0. but i don't think you can achieve. even you want you have to add string in multiple arraylist and each string add in at 0 position respectively.
why not try to make code simpler something like this

```
List<String> data =  new ArrayList();
data.add("demo1");
data.add("demo2");
.......

Fetching data at 0 position, you could do this

data.get(0);

Fetch all data, you could use for each loop

for(String s: data){
   //  here is you each position's data as string
}
```